# JavaScript - event.which always return 1 for hovering

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, mouse, mouseclick-event

I would like to *hover* & *mouse left click* at the same time on a `<div>` but `event.which` always returns 1 :

```
$('#element2').mouseenter(function(event) {
    switch (event.which) {
        case 1:  alert('Left Mouse pressed.');   break;
        case 2:  alert('Middle Mouse pressed.'); break;
        case 3:  alert('Right Mouse pressed.');  break;
        default: alert('You have a strange Mouse!');
    }
});
```

Complete example [here on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9je38h3c/4/).

A `mousedown` works but `hover` & `mouseover` & `mouseenter` always return 1.

Well if I replace `event.which` by `event.buttons` it returns the good result on Firefox but I red that `event.buttons` is not compatible with other browsers.

=> Is it a bug ? Do you have any browser compatible alternative solutions for my problem ? Thanks

Comment: Your fiddle works for me if you click first, hold down the mouse button, then hover over the div.

Comment: Works for me on chrome win7

Comment: Strange mouse for me. Chrome on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to handle it for all browsers (even i'm unable to replicate issue on chrome), you can use a global flag and check for it instead:

```
$(document).on('mousedown', function(e){
    window.btnClicked = e.which;
}).on('mouseup', function(){
    window.btnClicked = undefined;
});

$('#element2').mouseenter(function(event) {
    switch (window.btnClicked) {
        case 1:  alert('Left Mouse pressed.');   break;
        case 2:  alert('Middle Mouse pressed.'); break;
        case 3:  alert('Right Mouse pressed.');  break;
        default: alert('You have a strange Mouse!');
    }
});
```

Comment: Your solution works fine, thank you ! I will wait a little bit and mark your answer as the best solution if I don't see any easier alternative.